# Solidifier and Subdivision Mod behave weird

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, solidify-modifier

I want to do a model of a guitar. I need to smoothen the edges and thicken everything, but for some reason the modifiers behave weird. The Subdivision Mod should work on the whole body, but it only works on the sides and the solidifier also only works on some parts.

[image: The Subdivision Surface Modifier only smoothens the side, but the flat planes remain the same]

[image: and when I try to use the solidifier one of the planes also remains the same while other parts become thicker...]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=8lm12nOM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/8lm12nOM/) If somone wants to look at the model, here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices, it cuts off your object and therefore divides the effect of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]